# Installing 7zip in CentOS - succeeds; but can't use it

Tags: command-line, centos, 7-zip

I am trying to install 7zip to CentOS

```
yum install p7zip
```

installed it. And now running this returns

```
Package p7zip-9.20.1-2.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

But

```
[root@root public_html]# which p7zip
/usr/bin/which: no p7zip in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

So, why p7zip is installed but I cannot use it?

Comment: try $7zip as command...it works for ubuntu

Comment: Just looked at the package distribution, the binary file is `7za`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

> 7za

as a command.

[Samples for 7zip commands](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
you can find what command the package provides by `rpm` command:

> `rpm -ql`*package-name*`| grep bin`